# Single extension method on IDictionary<K, IEnumerable/IList/ICollection<V>>

Tags: c#, generics, extension-methods, covariance, generic-variance

I'm trying to write an extension method that will convert `IDictionary<K, S<V>>` holding any type of collection/sequence (`S<V>`) to `ILookup<K, V>` which is more proper data structure in those cases. This means I'd like my extension to work on different `S` types and interfaces:

- `IDictionary<K, IEnumerable<V>>`
- `IDictionary<K, ICollection<V>>`
- `IDictionary<K, List<V>>`

etc. Ideally, I don't want to write separate implementation for each possible collection type AND I want type inference to do its job.

What I've tried is:

```
public static ILookup<TKey, TValue>ToLookup<TKey, TCollection, TValue>(
    this IDictionary<TKey, TCollection> dictionary)
        where TCollection : IEnumerable<TValue>
```

But it have no `TValue` in parameters list, so type inference is unable to figure it out - I get "The type arguments for method ToLookup cannot be inferred from the usage".

Is there a chance it could work somehow in other way than adding fake `TValue`-typed parameter to the method?

**Examples of expected usage**

I hope all above calls to be possible and result in a call to my single extension method:

```
var dictOfIEnumerables = new Dictionary<int, IEnumerable<int>>();
var lookupFromIEnumerables = dictOfIEnumerables.ToLookup();

var dictOfICollections = new Dictionary<int, ICollection<int>>();
var lookupFromICollections = dictOfICollections.ToLookup();

var dictOfLists = new Dictionary<int, List<int>>();
var lookupFromLists = dictOfLists.ToLookup();
```

Comment: When you use it, try just specifying types explicitly for the generics

Comment: @Mgetz - I think it is exactly what NOtherDev tries to avoid - either specifying types explicitly or having fake arguments to force types. Sample of expected usage would probably clear things up.

Comment: Yes, as I've mentioned, I want type inference to do its job. Will add expected usage examples to the question.

Comment: _Is there a chance it could work somehow in other way than adding fake `TValue`-typed parameter to the method?_ I don't think so.

Comment: Does type inference break down for variant generics when creating non-extension static methods?

Comment: It would appear that type inference can't see that ICollection<T> : IEnumerable<T>.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because all collections implement `IEnumerable<T>`, we can just use it instead of the `TCollection` type paramter. Unfortunately the type inference does not know this. This is the code I wrote:

```
public static ILookup<TKey, TValue> ToLookup<TKey, TValue>
        (this IDictionary<TKey, IEnumerable<TValue>> dict)
{
    return dict.SelectMany(p => p.Value.Select
        (v => new KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>(p.Key, v)))
        .ToLookup(p => p.Key, p => p.Value);
}
```

There seems to be no way of making the type inference work, but this method will work if you cast the Dictionary:

```
((IDictionary<int, IEnumerable<int>>)dictOfLists).ToLookup()
```

Also you can add Lists to a Dictionary of IEnumerables and cast them back when you need them.

Answer (score 0):

From the bit of testing I've done, here are my results.

If I type `dictOfIEnumerables.ToLookup(`, I see 4 overloaded methods.
[image]

However, if I type `dictOfIEnumerables.ToLookup<`, I see all 5 overloaded methods.
[image]

It appears that type inference isn't working, because of name collision/resolution collision between the ToLookup() that is defined on IEnumerable. Apparently, without the angle brackets, it's resolving to the methods defined on IEnumerable, because that is what TCollection is restricted to. Maybe someone on StackOverflow that is smarter than I can explain to you why it works the way it does.

However, using the specified types does, in fact, work correctly on my machine.
[image]

Comment: Well, actually the issue is not due the name collision, the problem persists with `ToLookup2`. I know I can specify arguments explicitly, but that's exactly what I'm trying to avoid. It seems I need to go with duplicating the method for each interface...